# Generar un número long entre dos valores

Tags: java, poo, bucle-for, class, collection

He realizado este método para generar un código IBAN para una aplicación del ciclo que estoy estudiando. Quiero generar un número aleatorio entre 99999999999999999999 y 10000000000000000000. Los dos números son de 20 cifras y quiero que siempre se genere un número de 20 cifras. Me gustaría que fuese entre 99999999999999999999 y 00000000000000000001 pero no se si al pasarlo a la String se copiarán los 0 o sólo el 1 quedándose sólo en el código IBAN (ejemplo que quiero: ES00000000000000000001 y lo que no quiero sería: ES1).

He intentado hacerlo como vais a ver en el código, pero me dice int too long.

```
public String generarIban(){
    String codigoIban = "";
    String codigoBancoEsperanza = "1111122222";         // Código para saber que el IBAN pertenece a este banco.
    Random numeroAleatorio = new Random();
    long numeroIban = 0;
    boolean repetidoIban = true;
    
    do{
        //numeroIban = (long) (Math.random() * (99999999999999999999 - 10000000000000000000 + 1) - 10000000000000000000));
        numeroIban = numeroAleatorio.nextLong(9999999999 - 1000000000 + 1) + 1000000000;
        
        codigoIban = "ES" + codigoBancoEsperanza + numeroIban;
        
        for (CuentaBancaria lista: listaClientes){
            if (codigoIban.equalsIgnoreCase(lista.getIbanCliente())){
                repetidoIban = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    } while (!repetidoIban);
    
    return codigoIban;
}       // FIN DEL MÉTODO generarIban.
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo conseguí haciendo lo siguiente:

```
public String generarIban(){
    String codigoIban = "";
    String codigoBancoEsperanza = "1111122222";         // Código para saber que el IBAN pertenece a este banco.
    //Random numeroAleatorio = new Random();
    long leftLimit = 1000000000L;
    long rightLimit = 9999999999L;
    long numeroIban = 0L;
    boolean repetidoIban = true;
    
    do{
        //numeroIban = (long) (Math.random() * (99999999999999999999 - 10000000000000000000 + 1) - 10000000000000000000));
        //numeroIban = numeroAleatorio.nextLong(9999999999 - 1000000000 + 1) + 1000000000;
        //numeroIban = numeroAleatorio.nextLong((9999999999L - 1000000000L) + 1L) + 1000000000L;
        //numeroIban = numeroAleatorio.nextLong();
        numeroIban = leftLimit + (long) (Math.random() * (rightLimit - leftLimit));
        
        codigoIban = "ES" + codigoBancoEsperanza + numeroIban;
        
        for (CuentaBancaria lista: listaClientes){
            if (codigoIban.equalsIgnoreCase(lista.getIbanCliente())){
                repetidoIban = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    } while (!repetidoIban);
    
    return codigoIban;
}       // FIN DEL MÉTODO generarIban.
```

Espero que os sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).